# React - print statement causes page to reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have several React components, each of them connected to attributes from a database.

In one of them, I do the following print statement:

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props));
```

This stops the execution of the code and causes the entire page to reload.

I haven't written the code which connects to the database, I only know that it follows a Flux architecture.

Any ideas about what could cause this issue?

Comment: That can't be, can you reproduce this behaviour in a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: It is impossible for the code you paste above to cause a page reload - it must be something else - you're going to need to provide more code.